# Border gradient to transparent in QT CSS

Tags: html, c++, css, qt, graphics

do you know how to render a gradient to color transparent in a QT QTableView?

I know I should use some CSS stuff but online I can only find the regular web CSS solution which obviously doesn't work in QT (the QT CSS is a subset of the plain CSS language so we have no -Moz extensions, no IExplorer tricks and so on...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#resultWidget {
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 0px;
    spacing: 0px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #0080ff;
    background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 128, 255, 32), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) )
}
```

Did the trick. Result:

[image]

But I guess you meant QSS not CSS.